# Printing Char Elements Without Duplicates

Tags: java, arrays, char

i have this `char` array

```
char[] c = new char[]{'h','e','l','l','o','w','o','r','l','d';
```

i would like to look for duplicate elements in the array and print the elements in the array only once like so:

> h,e,l,o,w,r,d

i tried with this code

```
for (int j = 0; j < c.length; j++) {

                    if (c[j] == c[j]) {

                        System.out.println("Duplicate");

                    } }
```

how can i achieve this?

Comment: Are you allowed to use `Set`?

Comment: Yes, i Believe so

Comment: `Set<Character> unique = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(c));`

Answer (score 0):

Try it using Java 8:
`Arrays.asList(c).stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());`
to get the array back try:
`Arrays.asList(c).stream().distinct().toArray(size -> new Char[size]);`
Its all untested so Plesse let me know if these is something mit working.
For printing add `.foreach(System.out::println)`